# Bash: Scraping a text file to find phone numbers using bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal

I am trying to write a script using `grep` to find phone numbers in a text format.

The format for phone numbers is:

```
(XXXXX) XXXXXX
 XXXXX XXXXXX
(XXXXX)XXXXXX
```

I have written the following script but it doesnt seme to work:

```
grep -E -o "\b[0-9]\{5\}[0-9]\{6\}\b" webpage.html|
while read phone
do
    echo "$phone" >> testp.txt
done
```

Can someone help?

Comment: First of all, drop the `grep | while read ; do echo >> file` in favor of `grep >> file`. Then please describe what problems you are experiencing (for instance, for the input ... I expected the output ... but got ... instead).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
grep -Eo '\(?[[:digit:]]{5}\)?[[:space:]]?[[:digit:]]{6}' webpage.html > testp.txt
```

You will need to escape the opening and closing brackets. Search for and opening bracket 0 or 1 times, then 5 digits, a space one or more times and digits 6 times.

Comment: OP wanted to append to `testp.txt`, but you are truncating (`>`).

Comment: Looks like he is using only one html file and so only one write to the testp,txt file.